# How i can find which process running in a specific socket(IP:Port)?

Tags: networking

I need to find out process ID of a process which is running in a specific IP:Port

I have option to filter process using specific Port, but as my server having multiple IPs, so, And several process running with same port but with different IP. so, i need to find out the process which running with specific IP & Port.
Looking for hearing from you guys.

Comment: Which OS is this?

Comment: @muru 
OS is: RHEL or CentOS

Comment: Is manual inspection good enough? I usually just look at the output of `netstat -tulpn` but that can probably also filter since yyou already know the IP and port.

Comment: `lsof -t -n` is another options for a manual list.

Answer (score 0):

Will this be enough?

Say I am looking for a process listening on port 21 and IP of 192.168.168.2:

```
#ss -l -p  '( sport = :21  )' src 192.168.168.2

Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port              
tcp    LISTEN     0      32     192.168.168.2:ftp       *:*                     users:(("vsftpd",**pid=1444**,fd=3))e
```

Here `-l` looks for the Listening ports, `-p` forces to show PID.